# Writing a web app using Dropbox API

Tags: ajax, rest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to write a web app that uses Dropbox for cloud storage.
If I understand correctly, I should use the Restful API to achieve that.

[This documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api) exists and is quite good but being a newcomer to Restful API I would love to see and play with a simple example that works with this API.

My questions are:

1. Am I right to assume that Rest API is the way to go?
2. Is there a quick and easy example (Maybe a live example) to get me going?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you tagged your question with "ajax", i presume you want to do this entirely client-side (except for some proxy-code to be able to make requests accross domains)? I haven't tried it out myself, but there's [dropbox-js on google code](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/) which will at least give you some ideas (and if the Dropbox API didn't change too much since June 2010 it might even work out of the box)?

Update: there's no "download", but you can [browse the source code of trunk here](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-js/source/browse/#svn/trunk).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a lengthy article on the matter
[Some love for Javascript Applications](https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/08/some-love-for-javascript-applications-2/) with code samples, a demo etc.